# Representation of $U(n)$ group as a permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been experimenting with Cayley's theorem. I have trying to figure out a permutation representation for $U(10)$ and $U(5)$. However, I am having troubles conceptualizing this.

For example $U(10) = \{1,3,7,9\}$, but how do I go about formulating a permutation group from here?

If I can understand this, perhaps I can find some relation for all $U(n)$.

Comment: Which group does $U(n)$ refers to?

Comment: @AlexVong, most probably the units mod $n$.

Comment: U(n) = {x | gcd(x,n) = 1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the proof of Cayley's theorem: $u$ is identified with the permutation $x \mapsto ux$.

$1 \leftrightarrow (1,3,5,7)=(1)(3)(7)(9)$

$3 \leftrightarrow (3,9,7,1)=(1397)$

$7 \leftrightarrow (7,1,9,3)=(1793)$

$9 \leftrightarrow (9,7,3,1)=(19)(37)$

If you do the same for $U(5)$, you'll find that the representation is essentially the same, that is, $U(5)$ and $U(10)$ are isomorphic.

There isn't much hope to be able to say anything for all $U(n)$ because even for $n$ prime there is no formula for the elements of order $n-1$ (aka primitive roots).